# HL7 Validator PlanDefinition failed:

Tags: c#, hl7-fhir

I had to upgrade Hl7.Fhir.STU3 and Hl7.Fhir.Specification.STU3                              library and now I am getting error message that it can't resolution PlanDefinition profile.
I can see within the debugger that the specification.zip is being Extracted 
Extracted to 'C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Temp\FhirArtifactCache-1.2.1-Hl7.Fhir.STU3.Specification\specification'}

> Why will this not finding PlanDefinition?

```
{"Overall result: FAILURE (1 errors and 0 warnings)\r\n\r\n[ERROR] Resolution of profile at 'http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/PlanDefinition' failed: Cannot prepare ZipSource: file 'D:\\Users\\mcdevitt\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\FHIRValidatorFile\\FHIRValidatorFile\\FHIRValidatorFile\\bin\\Debug\\CustomProfiles' was not found (at PlanDefinition)"}

var HL7obj = new FhirXmlParser().Parse<PlanDefinition>(HL7FileData);
var coreSource = ZipSource.CreateValidationSource();
var cachedResolver = new CachedResolver(
            new DirectorySource(CustomProfilesPath, includeSubdirectories: true));

var combinedSource = new MultiResolver(cachedResolver, coreSource);

var ctx = new ValidationSettings()
        {
            ResourceResolver = combinedSource,
            GenerateSnapshot = true,
            Trace = false,
            EnableXsdValidation = true,
            ResolveExteralReferences = false
        };

var HL7validator = new Validator(ctx);
var result = HL7validator.Validate(HL7obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error comes from the ZipSource not being able to find a zipped file at the listed path. Instead of the path to a folder, please indicate the zipfile that you want to use as source.

From the 'coreSource' name, I assume that you want to point to the base FHIR specification. Instead of supplying your own zipfile for that, you can change it to this line:

```
var coreSource = ZipSource.CreateValidationSource();
```

The library will locate the specification.zip that comes with it, and will then be able to use it for validation against the core spec.

Comment: I did try that as well and get the same error - I can see the zip file being extracted

Comment: Could you check whether that directory gets filled with the specification files?